# Как получить данные из таблицы название которой находится в поле другой таблицы?

Tags: mysql, sql

Например, есть mysql-таблица:

```
id, name, table_name
```

Нужно получить `name` и значение поля `text` из таблицы, название которой находится в поле `table_name`, у всех полей, в которых поле `id` совпадает в обоих таблицах.

Comment: В общем виде никак. только динамическим SQL. Т.е. сначала получаете имя таблицы потом создаете с этим именем нужный запрос и выполняете его. А все потому, что SQL не предназначен для таких операций, в идеале надо спроектировать БД так что бы такого не требовалось

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.tablename, t2.text
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT 'tab1' tablename, t1_id, text
              FROM table2_1
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 'tab2'          , t1_id, text
              FROM table2_2
         /*   перечислить все "другие таблицы"
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 'tabN'          , t1_id, text
              FROM table2_N
         */
          ) t2
ON t1.name = t2.tablename
AND t1.id = t2.t1_id
```